# How to open a link after using rest api in Laravel?

Tags: java, php, laravel, rest, javafx

I've a java application that use Retrofit library to insert via api REST some data in the database of a Laravel application.

In the java app the user authenticates himself with the credential of the Laravel app (to make this thing I've used Laravel Passport) and after he stores some data in the db using the api REST that I've implemented in Laravel app.

So is there a way to open directly the link in which the user can see the data that he sent previously with the java app, without he have to login to Laravel app?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like you're asking how to do something "in Laravel" as your question suggests, but you need to figure out how to do it in java, not?  Otherwise, I'm seriously not understanding the question :-)

Comment: @DavidHeremans You're right, but in my question I told Laravel as the link I want to open in my Java application is the link of web app I developed with Laravel. I try to explain better what I need to do. Basically I can't open the page of Laravel app, if the user isn't logged in, but because the user makes the login in Java application, after he stored some data in the db of Laravel with the rest api, I would like to open the page where the user can see the data without he has to login in the Laravel app. It's a bit difficult for me explain this thing in English, but I hope you can understand

Comment: So your question is that your laravel application is losing its authentication?  Are you doing session based authentication, or how do you work?  I think you need to get your question more precise so we know what the exact issue is that you're facing.  You're giving very little to no context right now...

Comment: @DavidHeremans the first thing you need to understand is that the two apps do different things, but the java app can communicate with the Laravel app, storing some data in the db of Laravel app. To do this thing the user that use the Java app has to logged in with the account of Laravel app. After he makes the login in the java app he can store data in the db. So because he already makes the login in the java app, what I've to do is in the java app open dynamically the default browser and show the page that contains the data he sent before without makes the login in the Laravel app

Comment: and how does that user "log in" into that java app?  You mean the java and laravel app talk to the same database independently?

Comment: The db is in the Laravel app. The Java app can makes the login with Laravel Passport and to store data in the db I've implemented the REST api

Comment: So you did authenticate - you need to give more context as to what goes wrong, really...  So you have a passport token in your java application?  And you are then redirecting to a page on the laravel code?  Is that your use case?

Comment: @DavidHeremans Yes that's exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: Well, you need a way to transfer your token to the new page...  If your java and laravel are on the same domain, you could probably store the token in localstorage in the browser, set up some vuejs page in laravel, fetch the token there, and then fetch the information through ajax...

Comment: Or you can make a Middleware where you can use the token to programmatically login the user and redirect to the page you want